# Sum of List Comprehension Not Running Fast Enough

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three lists that I am using a sum of a list comprehension, however, having these lists of length n >= 1500 I've been unable to make my code run any more efficiently than ~3s per list comprehension.  This code needs to run thousands of times, so 3s per does not cut it.

Below is what my current attempt looks like.  The `split` is just a float determined earlier in my code.

```py
sum([list1[k] * (list2[k] == 1) if list3[k] < split else list1[k] * (list2[k] == -1) for k in range(n)])
```

`list1` contains 1500 positive floats between 0 and 1 which sum to 1.

`list2` contains 1500 randomly sampled -1's and 1's.

`list3` contains 1500 randomly sampled values from a normal distribution, an example would be `np.random.normal(5, 0.5, 3)`.

Comment: You should start using `numpy`.  It has methods to do these kinds of operations a vector at a time, instead of an item at a time.

Comment: [1] use numpy, [2] add to a function.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide test data. I just ran this with random data and it completed almost instantly.

Comment: Right.  I have to take N up to 150,000 before the result isn't instant.

Comment: Updated my post to include more about the data @MichaelRuth

Comment: Updated my post to include more about the data @TimRoberts, I see numpy seems to be the consensus, so I will definitely give it a go. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @namor129 Are your three "lists" variables python `list` or already numpy arrays? In the latter case, I could make my answer lighter.

Comment: Thank you for describing your input. I generated input accordingly and ran the summation, but still can't reproduce. The sum runs almost instantaneously. I'm getting 0.06s for n=1500. I understand that you'd like to improve the efficiency of this code, but I think that the time would be better spent figuring out what's going on with the system that's running it. The discrepancy between run time is too great to ignore and I don't think that `numpy` is going to make that much of a difference for summing a one-dimensional vector. Vectorization is most valuable for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: I did save 0.002s (3.3%) by converting the list summation to a generator expression summation: `sum(list1[k] * (list2[k] == 1) if list3[k] < split ...`. This should translate to a 5.4s reduction in run time for a 180s operation. Not much, but it certainly doesn't hurt and it should result in increasing runtime reduction as n increases.

Comment: @Guimoute they are currently lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing three approaches to your question: improved python, numpy, and numba.

- The improved python version based on @KellyBelly's comment works nicely. `zip` has a surprisingly strong effect on performance here.
- With numpy, you want to leverage the power of vectorized operations, turn your conditions into masks and get rid of loops entirely.
- Numba is usually the fastest solution if you feel at ease with its important concepts (`njit`, `prange`, etc.). It takes a bit more proof-reading than the numpy approach but it's well rewarded.

Note that those are only different ways of implementing the same algorithm. Improving an inefficient algorithm is very important too if you are chasing those precious milliseconds.

**Timings:**

| **Items** | **List comprehension** | **Zipped iterator** | **Numpy arrays** | **Numba.njit** | **Numba.njit(parallel=True)** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 k | 0.191 ms | 0.129 ms | 0.487 ms | 0.006 ms | 0.013 ms |
| 10 k | 2.288 ms | 1.206 ms | 0.477 ms | 0.048 ms | 0.019 ms |
| 100 k | 18.941 ms | 13.245 ms | 2.857 ms | 0.477 ms | 0.056 ms |

**Code:**

```py
# Imports.
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# Data.
N = 100000
SPLIT = 50
array1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, N)
array2 = np.random.choice((+1, -1), N)
array3 = np.random.randint(0, 100, N)
list1, list2, list3 = map(lambda a: a.tolist(), (array1, array2, array3))
print(N)

# Helpful timing function.
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def time_this():
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    yield
    dt = time.perf_counter() - t0
    print(f"{dt*1000:.3f} ms")

# List comprehension.
def list_comprehension():
    n = len(list1)
    return sum([list1[k] * (list2[k] == 1) if list3[k] < SPLIT else list1[k] * (list2[k] == -1) for k in range(n)])

# Zipped iterator.
def zipped_iterator():
    return sum(l1 if l2 == (1 if l3 < SPLIT else -1) else 0 for l1, l2, l3 in zip(list1, list2, list3))

# Numpy array.
def numpy_arrays():
    mask = array3 < SPLIT
    positives = array1[mask] * (array2[mask] == 1)
    negatives = array1[~mask] * (array2[~mask] == -1)
    return positives.sum() + negatives.sum()

# Numba.
@nb.njit
def numba_count():
    total = 0
    n = len(array1)
    for k in nb.prange(n):
        if array3[k] < SPLIT:
            sign = +1
        else:
            sign = -1
        if array2[k] == sign:
              total += array1[k]
    return total

# Numba in parallel.
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_count2():
    total = 0
    n = len(array1)
    for k in nb.prange(n):
        if array3[k] < SPLIT:
            sign = +1
        else:
            sign = -1
        if array2[k] == sign:
              total += array1[k]
    return total

# Timings.
totals = []
with time_this():
    totals.append(list_comprehension())

with time_this():
    totals.append(zipped_iterator())

with time_this():
    totals.append(numpy_arrays())

numba_count() # Compile before we time anything.
with time_this():
    totals.append(numba_count())

numba_count2() # Compile before we time anything.
with time_this():
    totals.append(numba_count2())

# Assert that all the returned values are identical.
assert np.isclose(totals, totals[0]).all()
```

Comment: your numpy solution improved my run time by 90% so that's great, I'll try out the others later, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to help! :) It was an interesting optimization problem.

Comment: Actually, let's not yield and sum zeros: `sum(l1 for l1, l2, l3 in zip(list1, list2, list3) if l2 == (1 if l3 < SPLIT else -1))`.

Comment: @namor129 Then you really had NumPy data already, didn't you? Should've been in the question, with a [mre], i.e., with code generating realistic inputs. And if you did have NumPy data, why did you write a list comprehension at all, instead of NumPy operations?

Comment: Note that Numba does not consider globals like CPython does. It is generally considered as a bad idea to use them (especially for arrays) unless there are constants since Numba assume them to be constants and can optimize the code consequently: it could even theoretically pre-compute the whole operation at compile-time (which is not the case here). As for CPython, globals should also be avoided because they are inefficient. In some case (eg. string concatenation), the algorithm can even become quadratic instead of linear beside a significantly bigger constant factor.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I agree that I should have written a proper signature for all the testing functions.

Comment: In fact, if you inspect the code generated by Numba, you can see that the compiler embed the array in the generated program generating a huge binary and making the compilation slower (not to mention the arrays must not change so the function is theoretically not really useful since it can be replaced with a copy of the result). It looks like the solution is still (mostly) computed at runtime by Numba. Put it shortly: it is better to pass the input in parameter during the function call.

Comment: Yeah, the missing Numba signature in the @njit also may causes the function to be lazily compiled at runtime during the benchmark and so the Numba timings are maybe over-estimated due to that (but the timings are pretty good already).

Comment: Note that a faster Numba function can be produced using `sign = np.int_(+1)` and `sign = np.int_(-1)`. This cause the `sign` variable to have the same size than the array items which causes the compiler to better vectorize the function using SIMD instructions. The generated code is pretty good.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The compilation time is not included in the timing. Notice how all the functions are run in the timing context manager except the two numba approaches that are called once before the measurements start. I will update the timings tonight after I include your and KellyBundy's suggested changes!